# Implementation of an amplifier in LTSpice

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, ota

I need to implement the following circuit in LTSpice but I don't know if my schematic is ok. Also, I don't know what  values for I should use for Cinf and R2.

The following constraints are imposed:

- VCC= 10V
- VCM = 1.5V
- Vgis a sine wave with a frequency of 1 kHz. Its amplitude will be chosen so as to ensure minimal distortion of the output signal (i.e. v0 should also be a sine wave)
- R1= 15kΩ.

I need to choose a value for R2 and Cinf in order to have a (theoretical)gain value Av=1500.

How can I compute the theoretical expressions of the DC collector currents of bipolar transistors Q1–Q8, considering VBE≈ 0.6V and the theoretical expression of the small-signal voltage gain Av= vo/vg?

The first picture is the schematic and the second is the LTSpice implementation.

What I found is that:

- ICq5=ICq6=ICq7=ICq8=(Vcc - Vbe)/R2
- ICq1=ICq2 = [ICq7 / 2 ] * [Beta/(Beta+1)]
- ICq4=iCq2-current of Q5
- ICq3=ICq1-current of Q3-current of Q4
- Beta in my case is 182.1 because I'm using a BC847A transistor.
- A=Vo/Vg = Gm_q2 * Beta_q5 * R1Gm_q2=ICq2 / Vt that is approx 40*ICq2

How can I find the value of R2?
This is what I have now, an sine like wave for Vg

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Those terms are all explained in the text below the schematic. What's unclear about them?

Comment: @BrianDrummond they are explained, but what should I put for Vcc? I can't just let a wire and that's it, I should put something there and idk what to put...

Comment: Oh. Use a voltage source component. set it to your desired supply voltage like 5V or 12V. Ditto Vcm (use 0.5 * VCC as a starting point; vary it to see what that does to the amplifier later). Vg is an AC source; start with 1 or 10 or 100mV, 1 kHz. And Cinf ... just set it to an impedance RL/10 or less at your lowest test frequency.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thanks! what values should I put for R2, C∞ in order to  a(theoretical)gain value Av= 1500?

Comment: I've already answered Cinf, and finding R2 is probably part of your exercise.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thanks, so this means i should put it to 1.5k, but at what, equivalent series resistance or equivalent parallel resistance?

Comment: @BrianDrummond What about R2? I can't find something...

Comment: @BrianDrummond can you please help me with a simulation in LTSpice?

Answer (score 1):

Here, my answer is similar to Spehro's with the following differences.

- hFE reduces sharply to 10% if Vce < ~0.5 @ 5mA due to saturation effects.

  - Vce(sat) increases with Ic depending on Q (up to 2V at Imax)
- Vcm >=1.5V depends on the load or negative feedback, if used.
- R1 (load) >= than R2 ( current bias)

[Proof of concept with 100 uV signal](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%203.5000000000000004e-7%205.692113234615338%2050%205%2050%0At%20224%20112%20192%20112%200%20-1%200%20-0.6339156189278246%20100%0At%20224%20112%20320%20112%200%20-1%200.017563955270928133%20-0.6339156189278246%20100%0Aw%20224%20112%20224%20160%200%0Aw%20192%20128%20192%20160%200%0Aw%20192%20160%20224%20160%200%0Aw%20192%2032%20320%2032%200%0AR%20416%2032%20416%200%200%200%2040%2010%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20544%20192%20544%20272%200%201000%0Aw%20256%20192%20256%20240%201%0Aw%20416%20192%20416%20240%201%0Ag%20256%20272%20256%20288%200%0Ag%20144%20272%20144%20288%200%0Ax%20192%20177%20210%20180%204%2016%20Q1%0Ax%20302%20172%20320%20175%204%2016%20Q2%0At%20160%20176%20192%20176%200%201%20-7.8660843810721754%200.6344278138813177%20100%0At%20352%20176%20320%20176%200%201%20-7.848527519822429%200.6344207198601355%20100%0At%20176%20256%20144%20256%200%201%200%200.652609884246114%20100%0At%20224%20256%20256%20256%200%201%20-0.21296230187256826%200.652609884246114%20100%0At%20384%20256%20416%20256%200%201%20-2.1872401023497576%200.652609884246114%20100%0At%20320%20128%20416%20128%200%20-1%206.508670439205376%20-0.6514795741987527%20100%0Aw%20320%20128%20320%20160%203%0Aw%20192%20192%20256%20192%200%0Aw%20256%20192%20320%20192%202%0Aw%20144%20224%20176%20224%200%0Aw%20176%20224%20176%20256%200%0Aw%20144%20240%20144%20224%200%0Aw%20144%20224%20144%20176%201%0Ar%20144%20176%20144%2032%200%201000%0Aw%20192%2032%20144%2032%200%0Aw%20176%20256%20224%20256%202%0Ag%20416%20272%20416%20288%200%0Aw%20384%20256%20272%20256%201%0Aw%20272%20256%20224%20256%200%0AR%20160%20176%20160%20144%200%200%2040%201.5%200%200%200.5%0Av%20384%20224%20384%20176%200%201%201000%200.0001%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20352%20224%20352%20240%200%0Aw%20384%20176%20352%20176%200%0Aw%20320%2032%20416%2032%200%0Aw%20416%2032%20416%20112%200%0Aw%20416%20144%20416%20176%203%0Aw%20464%20192%20416%20192%200%0Ag%20544%20272%20544%20288%200%0Ac%20544%20192%20464%20192%200%200.00001%20-3.2278969671155613%0A403%20576%20224%20672%20272%200%207_64_0_4353_10_0.0015625_0_2_7_3%0A403%20336%2064%20400%20128%200%2020_64_0_4355_10_0.00625_0_2_20_3%0Aw%20192%2032%20192%2096%200%0Aw%20320%2032%20320%2096%200%0A403%20432%20112%20528%20160%200%2039_64_0_12545_0.0001_0.010529027587883613_0_2_39_3%0A403%20576%20336%20672%20384%200%209_64_0_12546_4.688194288850779_0.0001_0_2_9_3%0A403%20288%20336%20400%20384%200%2034_64_0_12546_0.0001_0.0001_0_2_34_3%0Aw%20416%20192%20416%20176%200%0Av%20352%20224%20384%20224%200%200%2040%201.5%200%200%200.5%0Ax%20558%2061%20631%2064%204%2013%20hFE%5Cq100%5Csfixed%0A)

[image]

- open-loop gain is large Aol ~ 33k * R1/R2 (with hFE=100)
- > 10uV Vcm offset is significant with open loop.
- DC offset due to differences in Vcm and hFE, shown in [2nd simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%203.5000000000000004e-7%203.452441195350251%2050%205%2050%0At%20224%20112%20192%20112%200%20-1%200%20-0.6340076253618729%20100%0At%20224%20112%20320%20112%200%20-1%200.005725054116645367%20-0.6340076253618729%20100%0Aw%20224%20112%20224%20160%200%0Aw%20192%20128%20192%20160%200%0Aw%20192%20160%20224%20160%200%0Aw%20192%2032%20320%2032%200%0AR%20416%2032%20416%200%200%200%2040%2010%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20544%20192%20544%20272%200%201000%0Aw%20256%20192%20256%20240%201%0Aw%20416%20192%20416%20240%201%0Ag%20256%20272%20256%20288%200%0Ag%20144%20272%20144%20288%200%0Ax%20192%20177%20210%20180%204%2016%20Q1%0Ax%20302%20172%20320%20175%204%2016%20Q2%0At%20160%20176%20192%20176%200%201%20-7.865992374638127%200.6345198203157587%20100%0At%20352%20176%20320%20176%200%201%20-7.860458781237539%200.6343283595997016%20100%0At%20176%20256%20144%20256%200%201%200%200.6526098842461141%20100%0At%20224%20256%20256%20256%200%201%20-0.2128702954381272%200.6526098842461141%20100%0At%20384%20256%20416%20256%200%201%20-1.7978052281805144%200.6526098842461141%20100%0At%20320%20128%20416%20128%200%20-1%206.909852208094853%20-0.6397326794785183%20100%0Aw%20320%20128%20320%20160%203%0Aw%20192%20192%20256%20192%200%0Aw%20256%20192%20320%20192%202%0Aw%20144%20224%20176%20224%200%0Aw%20176%20224%20176%20256%200%0Aw%20144%20240%20144%20224%200%0Aw%20144%20224%20144%20176%201%0Ar%20144%20176%20144%2032%200%201000%0Aw%20192%2032%20144%2032%200%0Aw%20176%20256%20224%20256%202%0Ag%20416%20272%20416%20288%200%0Aw%20384%20256%20272%20256%201%0Aw%20272%20256%20224%20256%200%0AR%20160%20176%20160%20144%200%200%2040%201.5%200%200%200.5%0Av%20384%20224%20384%20176%200%201%201000%200.00009999999999999999%20-0.0001%203.141592653589793%200.5%0Ag%20352%20224%20352%20240%200%0Aw%20384%20176%20352%20176%200%0Aw%20320%2032%20416%2032%200%0Aw%20416%2032%20416%20112%200%0Aw%20416%20144%20416%20176%203%0Aw%20464%20192%20416%20192%200%0Ag%20544%20272%20544%20288%200%0Ac%20544%20192%20464%20192%200%200.000009999999999999999%20-6.009423108677776%0A403%20576%20224%20672%20272%200%207_64_0_4353_10_0.003125_0_2_7_3%0A403%20336%2064%20400%20128%200%2020_64_0_4355_10_0.00625_0_2_20_3%0Aw%20192%2032%20192%2096%200%0Aw%20320%2032%20320%2096%200%0A403%20432%20112%20528%20160%200%2039_64_0_12545_0.0001_0.008809101177184139_0_2_39_3%0A403%20432%20336%20528%20384%200%209_64_0_12546_6.065512364883899_0.0001_0_2_9_3%0A403%20288%20336%20400%20384%200%2034_64_0_12546_0.00019999998026087873_0.0001_0_2_34_3%0Aw%20416%20192%20416%20176%200%0Av%20352%20224%20384%20224%200%200%2040%201.5%200%200%200.5%0Ax%20558%2061%20631%2064%204%2013%20hFE%5Cq100%5Csfixed%0Ax%20583%20418%20635%20421%204%2013%20T.%5CsStewart%0Ap%20464%20192%20464%20320%201%204%0A38%2034%202%20-0.0001%200.0001%20%5Cs%5Cp/-%5Cs100uV%5CsDC%5CsOffset%0A) depends on hFE.
- also, the load current is DC offset from Vcc/2 due to connection at 0V thus be aware of DC offset voltage or use neg. FB.

Comment: So where it's the theoretical gain=1500??

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you mention are all external to the amplifier design.

Your SPICE schematic does not match the design. You need a Vcm voltage source and there should **not** be a current source connected to Q1 base.

Generally, you might start with Vcm = Vcc/2 and pick Cinf such that Xcinf << RL at the input frequency.

Eg. Vcc = 10, Vcm = 5, Vb= 100mV (AC) or whatever you want to use.

Comment: Please edit this new information into your question, not into the comments. 

And how are you doing with the calculation? R2 is a bias resistor so it's obviously going to affect the transconductance.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: oops edited wrong.... one

Comment: so...any answer @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm more used to thinking with FETS, tho bipolars are my preferred technology.

Takes a while to figure out WHAT IS BEING IGNORED. Clearly the Early Voltage params are not included.

Seems like the diffpair and active_current_mirror load are simply used to dump current into the base of that top PNP amplifier Q5.

Thus the transconductance of the diffpair/active_load is scaled by BETA of Q5, before converted into OUTPUT VOLTAGE across the load resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my short answer:

- The gain up to the base of Q5 is (app): **A1=-(gm_q2)hie_q5**

with:  gm_q2=Ic_q2/VT and hie_q5=hfe_q5(VT/Ic_q5) and Ic_q5=2Ic_q2

- The gain of the last stage is **A2=-R1(gm_q5)=-R1(Ic_q5/VT)**
- With **Ic_q6=2Ic_q2** the only **unknown quantity** in the total gain A=A1A2 is the current **Ic_q6**, which is determined by R2 and Vcc.
- The above calculation (I hope, it is without errors) neglects the transistor output resistances and, of course, the common mode gain.
- Final result: **A=0.5(R1/R2) * hfe * (Vcc-0.6)/VT**