# LTSpice amplifier simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I need to simulate the following circuit in LTSpice. I don't know where to ask so you're my only hope.. I made the scheme but I don't know what value to choose for R2 and Cinf in order to have theoretical gain Av=1500. The following constraints are imposed: Vcc=10v; VCM=1.5V; vg it's a sine wave with a frequency of 1Khz and R1=15kOhms. I need to simulate the circuit(transient, AC sweep), choosing an appropriate amplitude for vg in order to minimize output signal distortion(I put 100 uV but idk if it's correct..), and to specify a method for decreasing the voltage gain (without changing R1, R2, VCC or VCM). Implement the change and re-simulate the circuit in order to demonstrate the effect. Here it's the link for the LTSpice .asc scheme: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qL4ZDORlUAnp7sdpu3l2T4dKp_5WRAlH[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you think this question is any different to your previous several question asking for R2 and Cinf? [Link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/498287/implementation-of-an-amplifier-in-ltspice) to your original question (the others are closed as duplicates).

Comment: @DaveTweed not again man...

Comment: @Andyaka it's different because there I was asking for some theoretical aspects, now I m asking about simulations.

Comment: So, try out your simulation and fiddle with the values to get what you want. That's how folk tend to use simulators in many cases.

Comment: @Andyaka All I get it's a flat line and that's why I'm asking here, I don't understand why smart people don't want to help other people that are not that smart..

Comment: Also posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/ECE/comments/gqe22z/i_made_the_scheme_in_ltspice_but_i_dont_know_what/